# Использование медиазапросов

Tags: css3

Как медиазапросом можно отключить тег `<br>`? Т.е. текст записан в две строки, а надо на определенном разрешении переписать его в одну строчку.

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 767px) { .class br{display:none;}}

Comment: А зачем вы используете <br>? Не логичнее ли использовать тот же `padding` настроив так что - бы текст не влезал и переносился на другую строку, а через медиа запросы его убирать..... На мой взгляд так будет куда практичнее (имхо)..

Comment: в случае, если автор не может изменять html, падинги его не спауст

Answer (score 1):

Вот небольшой пример такого подхода:

```css
p {
  padding-right: 755px;
  }
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   p {
              padding-right: 0;
              }
  }
```

```html
<p>
  какой-то текст
</p>
```

Преимущество в том,что если вы будете добавлять еще строки текста, то вам не потребуются никакие бр - ы.